# What are my options for framing a thicker than average piece of artwork?

Tags: woodworking, hanging, custom-cabinetry

I have a piece of signed TV artwork that is mounted in cardboard frame aprox 1cm deep, that i want to hang on the wall. I've had a look round and most of the frames i've found aren't deep enough to fit the piece in.

What are my options for framing and hanging thick artwork?

Comment: Most any frame shop can custom build you exactly what you need. Otherwise, if the issue is that you need depth within the frame, google 'shadow box'

Comment: @DA01, can you please post this as an answer so it can be voted on and accepted?

Answer (score 1):

1cm isn't really "deep" for artwork. You won't find a photograph frame to fit it, but pretty much any frame for a canvas will be deep enough. You should be able to find these in arts / crafts stores that have a lot of frames. Often department stores will have only photo frames, so you'll probably have to look in more specialized shops.

Otherwise, any frame shop will have a ton of frame styles they can custom size for you. This will be a more expensive option, but you can get the artwork installed in the frame you select with very little work on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a framer build a frame that is essentially a plexiglass case for the work. Usually, the frame is 5 sides of plexiglass that are screwed into the solid backplane from the sides.The work can be mounted on the solid backplane. I would love to include a picture here but can't find any that show the correct side-view detail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a shadow box display case like [this website](http://www.meadowsdisplaycases.com/displaycaseprice.htm) has.  I'm sure you could find others on the web that might be closer to what you're looking for.